# Angular 6 : is there any chance of performance issue when using @HostListener?

Tags: rxjs, angular6

[image]I've an angular app , I want to automatically from the application if the user put the browser idle for a long period of time . Say 15 minutes . For that ive written a service and its working fine . I'm catching user action using @HostListener . But I feel like , there might be a chance for a performance issue as the HostListener method is called upon each user action .

```
@HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
  keyUpListenere(event) {
   this.idleTimeoutService.resetTimer();
   }
   @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
   clickListener() {
    this.idleTimeoutService.resetTimer();     
    }
   @HostListener('document:wheel', ['$event'])
   mouseWheelListener () {
    this.idleTimeoutService.resetTimer();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not at all, many applications use this kind of thing for automatic popup remiders of session timeouts. I would also include touchstart and/or touchend.

Comment: Adrian, do you care to explain shortly, or link to some source which explains why are HostListeners save to use, regarding memory?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are chance of performance, think that you are creating 3 listener that listen the actions on all your document.

You can assign this events on a main div of app.component on event functions, is better than make listeners.